# Can a druid remain in animal form indefinitely?

Tags: druid, adnd-2e

<sup>Edition matters, don't bite it before checking the tags...</sup>

The PHB does not state the duration of the druid's transformation into animals, only that they can become a bird, a reptile, and a mammal once per day.

How long can the druid remain transformed?

Comment: Grr... even though you warned me, I got halfway through a 1e answer before noticing I had the edition wrong!

Comment: @nitsua60 cheers. I was actually trying to fool all those newbies that would come and say *"but of course it only lasts for X hours. It is right there in the book.... ooh wait a minute"*

Comment: Why would you want to be anything else [if you can fly like an eagle?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zT4Y-QNdto)

Answer (score 12):

The druid can stay in animal form as long as they want, as quoted from The *Complete Druid's Handbook*, Page 7.

> Shifting shape takes one round, during which the druid cannot take
>   other actions. The druid can remain in the new shape indefinitely-the
>   duration of a form ends only when the druid turns back to the original
>   shape or assumes another one. A druid can shift from one shape to
>   another without returning to human form first.